# Can you iterate over chunks() with request.POST in Django?

Tags: django, flash, actionscript-3, image-processing

I'm trying to optimize a site I'm building with Django/Flash and am having a problem using Django's iterate over chunks() feature. I'm sending an image from Flash to Django using request.POST data rather than through a form (using request.FILES). The problem I foresee is that if there is large user volume, I could potentially kill memory.

But it seems that Django only allows iterating over chunks with request.FILES. Is there a way to:

1) wrap my request.POST data into a request.FILES (thus spoofing Django)

or

2) use chunks() with request.POST data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `chunks()` method is only available to an `django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile` object, which itself is a child of `django.core.files.base.File`.  From the [documentation for handling uploaded files](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files):

> The final piece of the puzzle is
>   handling the actual file data from
>   request.FILES. Each entry in this
>   dictionary is an UploadedFile object
>   -- a simple wrapper around an uploaded file.

So if you can create your own [`UploadedFile`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploadedfile-objects) object, then you could feasibly work some magic with `chunks()`.  I recommend snooping around on [DjangoSnippets](http://www.djangosnippets.org), which might have some code you can use as an example on how to do this.